# Max memory available in Windows 8 (truly usable)

Tags: windows, windows-8, ram, windows-8.1

In this website we can see that W7 pro is able to manage (physically) 192Go of RAM. (I'll talk only about x64)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_8

But we know it's a lie because the OS don't accept to manage that much. I can't have 32Go of RAM on a windows 7 pro, the OS will not use everything, I'm right? It will limit to 6Go I think, maybe 8Go.

So I would like to know about the windows 8 pro version, how much RAM can be managed by the OS?

This question is to know if it's useful to have 32Go of RAM or if 16Go are enough, because I don't think that W8 Pro will manage more than 16. But I don't remember where I learned that.

There is any change with windows 8.1?

Thank you.

Comment: (-1) for such a stupid question. The answer is already in the link you posted.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try SuperUser.

Comment: I didn't even know there was something else for no programming questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core Edition of Windows 8 can handle 128 GB and the Pro/Enterprise can handle 512 GB of physical RAM. This is explained in the link you posted.

Comment: But no! It's not possible to use 192Go of RAM on windows 7 even if I have them! If I have 16Go of RAM using x64 W7 pro I can't use all of them because there is some OS limitation from windows! Okay, the OS is maybe able to manage MAX 192Go, but Microsoft don't want that people using pro version use as much as 192Go RAM memory... I know people with W8 pro with 32Go RAM and they said me that the OS don't use all of them, because of some Microsoft limits. Am I wrong?

Comment: you are wrong. Windows does support so much RAM. I also have 16GB in Win7 and it works fine: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/stackoverflow/Win7_16GB_RAM.png If Windows can't use all RAM; there is a hardware limitation.

Comment: I thought there was also a Microsoft limitation, it's maybe only for x86 then...

Answer (score 1):

In a stock Windows installation, the OS limits your ram for some reason. The way to change it is tucked away in the settings:

Use the shortcut "windows button" + "r" to bring up the run window, then type in "msconfig", then go to the "boot" tab, then click "advanced options", and finally uncheck "maximum memory" and click apply. Now reboot and enjoy your full amount of ram.